# ASP.NET Core - How to get the Role of a particular user using his username at the point of Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Entity Framework using IdentityDbContext, I have this code:

**ApplicationUser:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationRole:**

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationUserRole:**

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

**LoginRequestDto:**

```
public class LoginRequestDto
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this Login Service.

```
    public async Task<Response<LoginResponseDto>> Login(LoginRequestDto model)
    {
        var response = new Response<LoginResponseDto>();
        var userRole = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == model.UserName).Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role).FirstOrDefault();
        var validityResult = await ValidateUser(model);
        if (!validityResult.Successful)
        {
            //_logger.Error("Login operation failed");
            response.Message = validityResult.Message;
            response.StatusCode = validityResult.StatusCode;
            response.Successful = false;
            return response;
        }

        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Message = "Login Successfully";
        response.Data = result;
        response.Successful = true;
        return response;
    }
```

As shown above, at the point of Login I want user the UserName to get the Role of that particular user, but it was displaying the UserName instead.

This is what I used:

```
var userRole = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == model.UserName).Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I resolve this to get the Role of the user at the point of login even if the login fails using the UserName?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
// Get the roles for the user
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

Note that you needd to resolve userManager service. You can find example below

```
private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;

public ExampleController(
    UserManager<User> userManager
    )
{
    this.userManager = userManager;
}
```

PS: Question does not have enough contextial information about how the registration is handled. I assumed that you are using ASP.NET Code Identity